# C# HttpClient Connection Aborted

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, httpclient

I'm using the following code to perform a POST request to an external application. This request originates from the controller of a .NET MVC application.

```
            using(HttpClient postClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            postClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
            postClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)))));
            postClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Crumb", crumb);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await postClient.PostAsync("url", httpContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
```

Which results in the following stack trace:

> [SocketException (0x2745): An established connection was aborted by
>   the software in your host machine]
>
> [IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine.]
>
> [HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.]

I removed the detailed lines because of company policy, I can add them back with omitted information if need be. I read setting the connection to close may solve the problem but that did not help. Is there any other solution?

Comment: try without the using block

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I don't have 50 reputations to add a comment.

That error is not caused by your code. Something eventually blocked the http stream of your program while debugging.

So turn off / close your anti virus and firewall and try again.